# How to create teaser articles on home page with "read more" link to article page

Tags: articles

I'm new to Joomla and I'm trying to create a home page that will show the 3 most recent articles, with only the first few lines of the article text, a thumbnail and a read more button for each which will navigate to the full article page.

I'm going through the plugins but there are hundreds so I thought I'd ask for help to save some time trying them all out.

[image: Here is what I'm trying to achieve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use [DisplayNews](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/frontend-news/736) for this. Works pretty well, lots of options for styling. A bit difficult if you want to do crazy customizations, but if you're going with the layout you've shown above there, you should be fine. It's got a lot of functionality built in, and do exactly what you're saying - show some text, a thumbnail, and a readmore.

Comment: Awesome, using DisplayNews and it worked just as I needed it to.

Answer (score 1):

Many templates include this kind of thing.  Rockettheme generally does, though we seldom use the feature.  There's a **free** template that provides it if you're interested in how they accomplish it called [Rockettheme Afterburner2](http://demo.rockettheme.com/joomla-templates/afterburner2/).  You probably have to register, but it is free, and it's reliable.