# Article - "Read more" button -> Link to other article

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4

I want to do something similar as asked in this question: [How to create teaser articles on home page with "read more" link to article page](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5649/how-to-create-teaser-articles-on-home-page-with-read-more-link-to-article-page)

How ever with the difference that I want to provide a custom link for the "read more" button that will point to another article.

So essentially I only want to provide the following information:

- Title
- Image
- Short text
- Article ID

When the user clicks on read more the article with the respective id will open.

Why do I need this, well I have a coverflow module at the top, then I want to show some smaller images, title and text below the coverflow module and when the user clicks on "read more" she should be forwarded to the same page as the coverflow points to.

Is this somehow possible with standard Joomla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this automatically, but we have some manual solutions.

If your template has 3-column design, you can use 3 **Custom HTML** modules,
 or you can create one row with 3 columns within a single Custom HTML module.

You can find this module in **Extensions** > **Modules** > **New** > **Custom HTML**

Best Regards!

Comment: I guess I will go with this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Zoo component from Yootheme. Was free and you can customize what you show in teaser and what you show in full article.

With this component you can do the same result you describe.

http://yootheme.com/zoo/

I holpe this helps.

Comment: This looks like SEBLOD which I have used in the passed, but I was really looking for a more lightweight solution. Still nice to know about it. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do this.

1. In article options turn off "show Read More"
2. In the article above the read more hr tag add

   ```
   <p class="read-more"><a href="your page url" class="btn">Read More</a></p>
   ```
3. Save and close article.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible with a standard Joomla.

For instance, you should implement a new editor button to enter the details and generate a button in the html article body.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you asked about, but it seems your question is concerned with placing a button inside an article, and that button links to a separate article when that button is clicked.  Unless I misread your original post, you are trying to use the Read More button to accomplish this, which likely will not work.

After a little trial-and-error, I found it rather easy to place a button in an article, that when clicked, links to another article.  I'm using Joomla 3.9 and the JCE Editor.  Follow along and you'll see how simple it really is.

First, you'll need to create and save the article you want to "link to".  Then, load the article you want to "link from" in the editor.

At this point, the editors don't offer a menu icon to insert a button, so you'll need to switch to the "code view" of the editor and enter the HTML button code manually.  This can be generic "opening tag", button text, and "closing tag" for a HTML button.  Place the button code where you want the button to appear in your article.  Then, switch back to the "editor view" (the WYSIWYG) view.  You should see the button in your article.

Next, double-click that button to select it.  Make sure the entire button is highlighted and selected.  Then, click the editor's "insert link" icon to fill in the url information for the article you want to "link to", just like you'd do with a standard text-based link.  That's all there is to it!

This process actually places the HTML button code *inside*  the usual HTML anchor tags.

Comment: Site stripped HTML tags.  Hope the idea still got across.

Comment: You can add any kind of code to your answer by wrapping it in backticks (inline code), or for code blocks: indent four spaces or highlight then press Ctrl+k on your desktop or highlight then click the code block formatting tool in the editor toolbar.